# VisualForce Download Large CSV File

Tags: csv

We want to provide user a feature to download case relared data. Is there a way we can achieve it asynchronously. Issues we are facing in synchronous way are:

1. Data is too large, so we are getting heap size error.
2. It is taking too long time, so we want it asynchronously.

Appreciate your help.

Regards
​Ankur

Comment: How big is this file you're trying to process?

Comment: @sfdcfox I am trying to download a file approx 50MB, and can't make any use of reports too, as I will be having filters in the query optionally, and reports don't support optional filters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so.
I recommend storing the file somewhere and give user a download link through streaming API (execution context will be different).

That makes sense in case where file size is between 6 and 12 Mb.